# How to convert a blob from db to a List<Object> in java

Tags: java, java-8

All I'm trying to do is to convert my java List to BLOB and vice-versa. I have successfully done the first part where I have converted my List and stored it as BLOB in DB. However, I'm to get the BLOB but unable to convert it back to List. I have tried searching at many places but not able to figure out a way to solve this problem I'm facing. Hope I'll get a solution here.

### Converting the List and storing it as BLOB in DB:

```
List<CustomerDTO> customersList = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
.
.
some code to store the data in to List<CustomerDTO>
.
.

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(customersList);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

// set parameters  
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

### Failed attempts of converting BLOB to List:

1)

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("CUSTOMERS_LIST");   
byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bdata);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

List<CustomerDTO> list = (ArrayList<CustomerDTO>) ois.readObject();
```

This attempt has given me empty list

2)

```
Stream<T> stream = (Stream<T>) rs.getBinaryStream("CUSTOMERS_LIST");
List<CustomerDTO> list = (List<CustomerDTO>) stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This attempt thrown me error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream cannot be cast to java.util.stream.Stream`

3)

```
IntStream bais = (IntStream) rs.getBinaryStream("CUSTOMERS_LIST");
Stream<Integer> stream = (Stream<Integer>) bais.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> ll = (List<Integer>)stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm lost here as I don't get how to convert `List<Integer>` to `List<CustomerDTO>`

Looking forward for your help.. TIA!

Comment: so you are basically serializing a list and deserializing it using java Serialization?

Comment: I also don't know much about which `Blob` are you using, but why are you reading from the first instead of the zero byte in this? `blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length())`

Comment: @Eugene No, the code I have shown here is all I tried

Comment: @Eugene java.sql.Blob it is

Comment: Did you implements Serializable in CustomerDTO class?

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan No, it's just a POJO

Comment: I have faced same problem but when I implements Serializable with a version variable, it worked.

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan well in that case you can share me your solution and i will see if it works for me too. Also let me know which code I need to  test in the given 3 solutions by me.

Comment: Try your first attempt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183485/discussion-between-mannedear-and-md-nasir-uddin-bhuiyan).

Comment: When your JOJO does not implement `Serializable`, your first code fragment (the method used to store them) would not work. Except when the list is empty. That would explain perfectly, why your first restore attempt restores an empty list.

Comment: @Holger I have implemented `Serializable` to my POJO and stored the value into DB, tried to retrieve the BLOB and converted to `List` but it's still empty.

Comment: As said, when your first attempt of storing the list did not fail despite the objects were not serializable, the list was empty during this test. So you have a problem in the “some code to store the data in to `List<CustomerDTO>`” part. This problem does not disappear when implementing serializable.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your first attempt slightly as follows:

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("CUSTOMERS_LIST");   
byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
ArrayList<Object> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
for(byte b : bdata) {
    arraylist.add(new Byte(b));
}
```

Comment: done the same but got this one when checked `arraylist>>[-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 19, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 65, 114, 114, 97, 121, 76, 105, 115, 116, 120, -127, -46, 29, -103, -57, 97, -99, 3, 0, 1, 73, 0, 4, 115, 105, 122, 101, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 119, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120]`

Comment: Also how do I change `arraylist` to `List<CustomerDTO>` ?

Comment: @mannedear instead of ArrayList<Object> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();  use List<Object> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Throwing me compilation error when I try to convert `List<Object>` to `List<CustomerDTO>`, so I changed the code this way `List<CustomerDTO> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(byte b : bdata) {
            arraylist.add(new Byte(b), null);
        }` but it's throwing me error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -84, Size: 0`

Comment: Above ArrayList is the byte array which you need to convert to your respective type. For example, if you need to convert byte array back to the original file, which is in pdf format FileOutputStream class is used.